# Verb Int. & Adv

Tags: transitivity

In my grammar book it has  been written that intransitive verb usually takes their adverbs immediately after them. But in the following sentence from *[Goodbye, Mr. Chips!](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks05/0500111h.html)*, it does not happen as gave takes the object (an impact):

> So there were; he had been leaning his elbows on them; they were all addressed to him by name. He tore them open one after the other, but each contained nothing but a blank sheet of paper. He thought in a distant way that it was rather peculiar, but he made no comment; **the incident gave hardly an impact upon his vastly greater preoccupations.** Not till days afterward did he realize that it had been a piece of April-foolery.

Comment: *hardly* is part of a modifier on the direct object *impact*, not on the verb. But are you sure you've transcribed this correctly? --I'd expect *hardly **any***, and I note that *preoccupations* is misspelled. In any case, *gave him* is unidiomatic: things *have* an impact, not *give* an impact.

Comment: yeah! there is no mistake ...the book also states as it is!

Comment: I'm confused.  I see a statement about intransitive verbs -- verbs without objects --  and an example of a transitive verb -- with its object clearly identified.  In the original version of this post I can see that "hardly" is the adverb in question, and I can imagine several possible points of confusion regarding that word.  But, what's the question here?

Comment: question is about placement  of adverb!

Comment: Please note that fiction authors (whether good or bad) take liberties with grammar in order to change how the sentence impacts the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Placing of adverbs seems like a really complex issue, and the rules are 'flexible' depending on the type of adverb, and a range of other things.

The short answer to your question is that the 'rules' are not set in stone, depending on particular words and context.

I am taking your question to relate to the placing of 'hardly'.

Usually one would expect:

> The incident hardly gave an impact upon ...

Grammar websites [like this one](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/word-order/adverb-position) tell us that 'adverbs of frequency [and I believe hardly is in effect an adverb of frequency here] are put directly before the main verb'. However, the rule is flexible. Authors, especially authors of literary works, will be more creative with their writing.

Here are the four examples cited by the website I linked to, which gives (wrongly) the view this is the **only** way to use adverbs in these sentences.

> I often go swimming in the evenings.
>
> He doesn't always play tennis.
>
> We are usually here in summer.
>
> I have never been abroad.

I can rewrite each sentence with the adverb in a different place which would be acceptable in standard English.

> I go swimming often in the evenings.
>
> He doesn't play tennis always.
>
> Usually we are here in summer.
>
> I never have been abroad.

Moving the placing of the adverb can cause a slight change in emphasis, which skilled writers will use to their advantage.

I suspect it's easier to learn the acceptable placements by usage, having learned the most common placements, than it is to try to find hard and fast rules which you can rely on.